# Quotient of orthogonal group $O_{2}$ by it's center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Let be $O_{2}$ the orthogonal group, that is, the group of reflections and rotations of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. His center is $\{ \pm I\} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. I'm having problems to study the center of the quotient $\frac{O_{2}}{\{ \pm I\}}$. Someone could clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by “to study the center”?

Comment: You really mean $Z(O_2/\{\pm 1\})$?

Comment: Yes, in general, what is $\frac{O_{2}} { \pm I}$? I think the center is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$...

Comment: The quotient group still consists of all orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrices  up to sign. So nothing has changed, except identifying $A$ with $-A$. The group  $O_2$ is infinite and its center isomorphic to $C_2$. But you were asking about the center of the quotient group, which is different.

Comment: In fact $, O_2/\{\pm I\}$ has trivial center. Moreover generally, $O_n/\{\pm I\}$ has trivial center.

Comment: This argument doesn't work. If [A] represents the image of A in the quotient group, then [A][B] = [B][A] means that AB = BA or AB = -BA. This is *not* equivalent to A commuting with -B, since as you point out, that is equivalent to A commuting with B itself. But the matrices might anticommute instead. So what you need to show is that if an orthogonal matrix either commutes or anticommutes with every orthogonal matrix, then it must be I or -I.

Comment: I have found that $\pm I$ and rotations by $\pm π/2$ are in the center of quotient. Indeed, rotations by $\pm π/2$ commutes with rotations and anticommutes with reflections, then, i think, are in the center. Thus, the center isn't trivial. Otherwise, we need matrices that only anticommutes or only commutes.

Answer (score 1):

$O_2$ is generated by rotations and symmetries, which means that all the elements of $O_2$ can be written as $R_\theta S^\epsilon$, where $R_\theta $ is a rotation of an angle $\theta$, $S= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\epsilon \in \{0,1\}$. Though it suffices to look for matrices in that form such that $S R_\theta S^\epsilon = \pm R_\theta S^{\epsilon+1}$ and $R_\alpha R_\theta S^\epsilon= \pm R_\theta S^\epsilon R_\alpha$ $\forall \alpha$. This lies to all those matrices such that $S R_\theta=\pm R_\theta S$ and $R_\alpha S^\epsilon= \pm S^\epsilon R_\alpha$ $\forall \alpha$, which are separate conditions for $\theta$ and $\epsilon$. 
Can you now find out who's the center?

Answer (score 0):

I was ignoring the part "anticommutes with every orthogonal matrix". Indeed, we can look to commutators:

\begin{align}  
  [Rot(\phi), Ref(\psi)] &= Rot(-2\phi)\\
  [Rot(\phi), Rot(\psi)] &= I_{2}\\
  [Ref(\phi), Ref(\psi)] &= Rot(4(\phi - \psi))          
\end{align}

If $AZ(O_{2})$ $\in$ $Z\Big(\frac{O_{2}}{Z(O_{2})}\Big)$:

$$ (AB)Z(O_{2}) = (BA)Z(O_{2}) \Rightarrow [A,B] = \pm I_{2}$$

Looking to the commutators above, because $B$ is arbitrary, $A$ must be a rotation, say $Rot(\phi)$, and $Rot(-2\phi) = \pm I$, which implies $\phi = 0, \pi$ or $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence:
                $$Z\Big(\frac{O_{2}}{Z(O_{2})}\Big) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{2}$$

So, the center of the quotient isn't trivial.

Comment: Still not quite. Check your quantifiers. You want the orthogonal matrices A such that for every orthogonal matrix B, either AB = BA or AB = -BA. This is not (necessarily) the same as the union of the matrices that commute with everything along with the matrices that anticommute with everything, although that union is definitely a subset of the center. You still need to rule out every matrix that commutes with some matrices and anticommutes with the rest.